# Will apache poi work with J2Me?

Tags: java-me, apache-poi

I wish to use [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/index.html) libraries for accessing powerpoint files in a blackberry application I am developing. Adding the jar's as external libraries causes preverification errors. (compiles successfully). 
My question - Can I use apche poi libraries in a J2ME application?
If not is there a version of apche poi available for use with J2ME?

Answer (score 3):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) will not compile in J2ME since it's written in J2SE. To use in J2ME it needs to be ported.

[Apache POI - How to build](http://poi.apache.org/howtobuild.html):

> POI 3.5 and later requires the JDK version 1.5 or later. Versions prior to 3.5 require JDK 1.4+

See also [Apache POI Mobile device support](http://markmail.org/message/2sgklulmalvmmojk)

Answer (score 0):

Use POI on a server and let your j2me become a fat client that has the server do the heavy work.